# MySql how to make an ID with 6 nubers

Tags: mysql

Simple question: how to make id when creating table in mySql go like this 0001 0002 and so on instead  of 1 2 3..

Sorry but don't know how to ask this in a correct way for Google to understand :)
And I am beginner so please make answer simple
Thanks

Edit: got answer

Comment: So you want auto_increment with leading 0?

Comment: You'd pad numeric data with leading zeroes when you *display* it, not when you *store* it.

Comment: I want id to be made of 4 numbers from the start and as I understand default id is made of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is... you don't.

Numeric data isn't stored in a formatted way.  It's stored as numeric values.  You can, however, *display* that data however you like when you query it.

For example, to take a number that's 4 digits or fewer and pad leading zeroes, you might do something like this:

```
SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(`ID`, VARCHAR(4)), 4, '0') FROM Table
```

This would convert the `ID` column to `VARCHAR(4)` in the resulting data, and left-pad the values with `'0'` characters up to a length of `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the Field with Zerofill. So MySQL fill it with 0 to the lenght you specified

```
CREATE TABLE `num` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


MariaDB [test]> select * from num;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 0001 |
| 0002 |
| 0003 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the zeros when you select the values:

```
SELECT LPAD(id, 4, '0') as id FROM your_table;
```